# Eloquent query with "LIKE" statement doesn't work in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to make an user search engine that uses a string to compare it with the user name of each user inside a collection and return those that have that string as a substring of its user name and I have an `User` model related with itself in my `Laravel` project, this is a `many to many` relationship with `follower_followed` pivot table, this tables are generated via migrations, the `up` method of both migrations are showed bellow.

`up method inside create_users_table migration.`

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements("id");
        $table->string("username", 15);
        $table->string("name", 35);
        $table->string("lastname", 35);
        $table->string("country", 35)->nullable();
        $table->string("city", 35)->nullable();
        $table->string("phone_number", 35)->nullable();
        $table->string("email", 35)->unique();
        $table->string('biography', 120)->nullable();
        $table->string("password", 255);
        $table->bigInteger("role_id")->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->timestamp("email_verified_at")->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```

`up method inside create_follower_followed_table migration.`

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('follower_followed', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger("follower_id")->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger("followed_id")->unsigned();
        $table->foreign("follower_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
        $table->foreign("followed_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now, the relationships are defined in the `User` model like this.

`User model.`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject{

    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        "role_id",
        "username",
        "name",
        "lastname",
        "country",
        "city",
        "phone_number",
        "email",
        "password",
        "biography"
    ];
    
    protected $hidden = [
        "role_id",
        "password",
        "remember_token",
        "email_verified_at",
        "deleted_at",
        "created_at",
        "updated_at"
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
        "email_verified_at" => "datetime",
    ];
    
    protected $appends = [
        "following"
    ];
    
    protected $with = ["profile_picture"];
    
    public function getFollowingAttribute(){
        return DB::table("follower_followed")
            ->where("follower_id", Auth::user()->id)
            ->where("followed_id", $this->attributes["id"])
            ->exists();
    }
    
    public function getJWTIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    
    public function getJWTCustomClaims(){
        return [];
    }
    
    public function getRouteKeyName(){
        return "username";
    }
    
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    
    public function profile_picture(){
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfilePicture::class);
    }
    
    public function followers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "follower_followed", "followed_id", "follower_id");
    }
    
    public function followed(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "follower_followed", "follower_id", "followed_id");
    }
}
```

Finally I have in my `UserController` the following method.

`UserController`

```
public function searchFollowed($username){
    
    $user = Auth::user();
    
    $user->load([
        "followed" => function($query){
            global $username;
            $query
                // ->select(["id", "usename", "name", "lastname"])
                ->where("username", "like", "%$username%");
         }
     ]);
     
    return response()->json($user->followed);
}
```

It is related with the following route defined inside `api.php` routes files.

```
Route::group(["namespace" => "API"], function(){
    Route::get("search_followed/{username}", "UserController@searchFollowed");
}
```

All this doesn't work correctly because `searchFollowed` method return all the `followed` users  loaded via `lazy eager loading` regardless the method argument string also if I uncomment the commented line inside the this method I get the exception `` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `usename`, `name`, `lastname`, `follower_followed`.`follower_id` as `pivot_follower_id`, `follower_followed`.`followed_id` as `pivot_followed_id` from `users` inner join `follower_followed` on `users`.`id` = `follower_followed`.`followed_id` where `follower_followed`.`follower_id` in (1) and `username` like %%) ``. I hope my intentions are clear.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408610/laravel-like-query-is-not-working) but doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$username}%") use like this

Comment: I already did it... I put the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408610/laravel-like-query-is-not-working).

Comment: whats the output of `dd($query);` ?

Comment: $user->load(["followed" => function($query) use ($username) {
                    $query->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$username}%");
                }
            ]); => use like this way

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya Wow... That work, thank you !

Comment: @fahico98 Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user->load(["followed" => function($query) use ($username) { $query->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$username}%"); } ]);
```

Hope fully it will help to you easily

Comment: I don't need the curly brakets in `"%{$username}%"`.